# How to build a shared library for TensorFlow on Travis-CI

Tags: ruby, tensorflow, travis-ci, bazel

I'm assisting in building a [Ruby-wrapper](https://github.com/Arafatk/tensorflow.rb) for [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). Obviously. we'd want to setup automatic test of the project and so I'm [currently](https://github.com/chrhansen/tensorflow.rb/pull/1/files) <strike>trying</strike> struggling to configure Travis-CI to build the project and run tests like I can on my own machine (OSX El Capitan).

My question is: What is the magic that needs to go in the `.travis.yml`-file to properly `bazel build` a shared lib (`tensorflow.so`) for TensorFlow?

As far as I can tell, I've successfully installed [TensorFlow's dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#installing-from-sources), including Google's build tool [Bazel](http://www.bazel.io/), but Travis-CI still can't build. As of this writing the `bazel build` command fails with the message:

```
...
...
INFO: Building...
[1 / 13] Writing file external/gif_archive/libgif.so-2.params
[3 / 13] Compiling external/gif_archive/giflib-5.1.4/lib/egif_lib.c
ERROR: /home/travis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_travis/1a58902034d650eeef2a9da5b1248179/external/gif_archive/BUILD:14:1: C++ compilation of rule '@gif_archive//:gif' failed: namespace-sandbox failed: error executing command 
  (cd /home/travis/.cache/bazel/_bazel_travis/1a58902034d650eeef2a9da5b1248179/execroot/tensorflow && \
  exec env - \
...
...
The command "bazel build --verbose_failures=1 @gif_archive//:gif" failed and exited with 1 during .
```

https://travis-ci.org/chrhansen/tensorflow.rb/builds/145716589

Note: I've noticed that the guys over at github.com/node-tensorflow/node-tensorflow successfully made this happen: https://travis-ci.org/node-tensorflow/node-tensorflow/builds

UPDATE: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3374

Comment: Can you try disabling sandboxing?

Comment: Sure, how would I do that? Here's my current [`.travis.yml`](https://github.com/chrhansen/tensorflow.rb/pull/1/files). Google wasn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Try using `bazel build --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so`; that should disable sandboxing.

Comment: Should we close this, since the github issue seems to have been solved?

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been solved (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3374), you should be able to build tensorflow with sandbox enabled.